# How to set image size same as container font-size

Tags: html, css, svg

I have this html code:

```
<p>text <span class="icon svgicon"><img src="img.svg" /></span></p>
<p>text <span class="icon svgicon"><svg>...</svg></span></p>
```

Lets say the paragraph and the span have the font-size 16px. Is it possible to make the image have the same height ( 16px ) using CSS?

I want to make somehow to image inherit the height from the span's font-size so i wont need to customize it for every place where i put it.

This are supposed to be some svgicons.

Last resort would be to make a JS to parse all icons see the holder font-size and set the height.

Thanks.

Comment: I want to read somehow the font-size property of the parent. To use variables would require to add the fontsize as a variable everywhere ( i'm not too used with them, so i might got it wrong ). Not to mention it isn't supported by IE11

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you accomplish it by setting image height relative to the font height and setting the image width to auto like so:

```css
.svgicon img, .svgicon svg {
  height: 1em;
  width: auto;
}

p, span {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<p>text <span class="icon svgicon"><img class="custom" src="img.jpeg" /></span></p>
<p>text <span class="icon svgicon"><svg>...</svg></span></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give the image a height of `1em` which will be relative to the parent font-size.

```
.icon {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.icon > img,
.icon > svg {
  height: 1em;
}
```